# Little Endian and Big endian c program

Tags: c

Can someone tell me if I did the following program correctly? It is supposed to print either Little or Big depending on whether the machine is little endian or big endian.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;   

    unsigned char *c = (char*)&x; 

    if (*c)
        printf("Little");
    else
        printf("Big");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, except that you probably meant to cast to an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: can you explain haha sorry im not that great with C! @VaughnCato

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview

Comment: Pedantically, better code would be `if (*c == 1) printf("Little"); else printf("Not Little");`

Answer (score 3):

The code is almost correct:

- you should cast `&x` as `(unsigned char*)&x`
- you should `printf` a trailing `'\n'` after `Little` or `Big`.

Further work:

- you could simplify the code by getting rid of `c`.
- make it even simpler: get rid of `if` and use the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

My laptop is "Little":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 1;   

    unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*) &x; 
    printf( (*c) ? "Little\n" : "Big\n");

    return 0;
}
```